# regex taking over 1000 minutes to complete

Tags: c#, regex, multithreading, visual-studio, csv

The code below reads a list of words from the file named WORDS then it uses those words and looks for them in the file named CONTENT then it deletes those words from CONTENT and replaces them with ###### and creates a new file named FINAL - the words file has about 16k rows of words, the CONTENT file has about 16k rows and about 8 millions words in total - when I ran this it was taking over 1000 minutes to complete I eventually gave up.

Is there any way to speed this process or use something significantly more efficient ? the words in Words start with \b and end with \b - the code does work as i tested on a smaller CONTENT file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string SAR_CONTACTS = @"C:\Users\root\Desktop\WORDS.csv";
            string SAR_CONTENT = @"C:\Users\root\Desktop\CONTENT.csv";
            string READ_SAR_CONTACTS;
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(SAR_CONTENT, Encoding.UTF8))
            READ_SAR_CONTACTS = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

            string SAR_CONTACTS_FILE = File.ReadAllText(SAR_CONTACTS);
            string SAR_CONTENT_FILE = SAR_CONTACTS_FILE.Replace("\r\n", "|");
            SAR_CONTENT_FILE = SAR_CONTENT_FILE.Remove(SAR_CONTENT_FILE.Length - 1);
            string SAR_CONTENT_CENSORED = Regex.Replace(READ_SAR_CONTACTS, SAR_CONTENT_FILE, "######", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\root\Desktop\FINAL.csv", SAR_CONTENT_CENSORED);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, create a hash set with words, then simply read one word at time from contents and look it up in the set creating FINAL as you go along.

Comment: take a look at this to see if it's helpful for you https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12383/Aho-Corasick-string-matching-in-C

Comment: First, please stop using SHOUTING_SNAKE_FORM in C#; it makes your code hard to read. In C# we use `camelCasedIdentifiers` for locals. Second, this is a really bad use of regular expressions; they were not designed for this task. Use a different search-and-replace mechanism if you have more than a handful of replacements. Regular expression replacement was designed for dealing with just a few replacements, not millions.

Comment: InBetween - the list of words are well over 18k words not sure how that would be achieved

Comment: Will people stop flagging the comments here. Eric Lippert is giving good advice. Straight forward advice is not rude.

Comment: @MH731Z your comment is deleted, as it wasn't helpful and I've been drawn to this post repeatedly for comment flags.

Comment: Could you show/upload to cloud WORDS file?

Comment: JohnyL sorry I cant because it has confidential content however it basically looks like this,

\bjohn\b
\balex\b repeated 16k times for different names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simply throw Regex out the window for this in general since it can get complex pretty quickly for such an extensive file. Using your contacts file, instead of `\b`, I'd probably substitute that with a set of delimiters, such as `£&%` (this will break if there are contacts with literally the same string of delimiters in that order).

This is how I'd write it - note that in terms of efficiency, this may not be the most efficient, but it will work. Also note, I've added the VB version of `Replace` so that case is ignored as the C# version does not have this overload (you could also write an extension function instead).

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string contacts = @"contacts.csv";
            string content = @"content.csv";
            string[] delimiter = { "£&%" };
            string read_contents;

            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(content, Encoding.UTF8))
                read_contents = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

            string sar_contacts = File.ReadAllText(contacts);
            List<string> contactsToReplace = sar_contacts.Split(delimiter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

            int i = 0;
            foreach (var wordToCensor in contactsToReplace)
            {
                read_contents = Strings.Replace(read_contents, wordToCensor, "######", 1, -1, Constants.vbTextCompare);
                Console.WriteLine(++i); // so we know where we are
            }

            File.WriteAllText(@"filtered.csv", read_contents);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: many thanks for your detailed response sushi7777 I will test this and confirm if its doing this quicker

Comment: Uploading all 16k rows and 8mln words into memory?

Comment: why not? it's a crude way but it's not going to take longer than 1000 minutes and this is a basic programming example which is what i was going for in this case

Comment: so i tested the code above, my old code does a sample file in 90 seconds , sushi7777's code takes about 60 seconds but has issues in a sense its deleting parts of words too, I'm wondering if this is the maximum limit of how quickly this can happen

Comment: I just ran the code on the main file, at this rate it will complete in 9.4 hours lol

Comment: Much quicker than 16 hours :D